# Write ByteArrayOutputStream to FileOutputStream vs Write ByteArray to FileOutputStream?

Tags: java, arrays, file, memory-management, bytearrayoutputstream

Which one of below approach is more efficient in term of memory utilization & performance:

1. Write `ByteArrayOutputStream` to `FileOutputStream` i.e `baos.writeTo(output);` or
2. Convert `ByteArrayOutputStream`  to  `ByteArray` and then write to  `FileOutputStream` i.e `output.write(baos.toByteArray());`

I have analysed and found that the 2nd approach is taking more memory while writing to file since `baos.toByteArray()` creates a newly allocated `Byte` array.

Please suggest. Do you think is there any benifit of using `output.write(baos.toByteArray())`?

```
FileOutputStream output = new FileOutputStream(path);
ByteArrayOutputStream baos = getBaos(); 
baos.writeTo(output);
//output.write(baos.toByteArray());
```

Comment: Neither. Why do you have the entire byte array or the `ByteArrayOutputStream` in the first place? The best approach is to read the source in chunks of say 8K and write it directly to the output.

Comment: Thanks, @user207421 for quick feedback.

Goal is to write poi SXSSFWorkbook to the output stream using ByteArrayOutputStream
I don 't think there is a way to read the poi workbook in chunks and write it directly to the output.
I thought to skip the intermediate step  to save some memory (Writing workbook to  ByteArrayOutputStream ) 
and tried writing workBook directly to the output stream, but it'
s very slow.
    i.e workBook.write(os);
 Please suggest
if you have a better way to do this end goal is to write SXSSFWorkbook to FileOutputStream efficiently.

Answer (score 0):

writeTo writes **directly** its internal buffer to OUT (i.e. FileOutputStream) while write(bao.toByteArray()) takes more time than writeTo as you've correctly analyzed.